# When to and when not to apply comic relief?

Tags: gm-techniques, npc

A recent talk with my players revealed that they wanted me to add characters akin to a comic relief character I presented in an earlier campaign. While I have really wanted to add more comic relief characters, I really don't want to overdo it.

**The Group**

We are doing a heavy sandbox game. The players are to decide their own place in the world, and I will let the world react towards that. The idea is to have heavy role-play involved. Thus it would be best if the story could be kept in character, and the comic relief doesn't break immersion.

**What they remember**

The reason why they mentioned it, is a paladin I once made, which was this character that insulted the party being a douche bag good guy, only to shortly after run to his own death and be sliced into 2 by their enemy in 2 strikes. They never forgot about him, and he became a very memorable character for them ever since, each time his miniature appears on the game board he is recalled etc.

So any advice on how to know when its overdone. Or any stories of well done npcs adding comic relief to an otherwise serious game.

Comment: I think this question is too broad as it stands. Reasons for including a comic relief are numerous, as are the techniques. Could you specify what game are you playing, what is your usual mood and themes? Any idea about why your players wanted comic relief in the first place?

Comment: Just close it, I can't think of a way to specify it further without it losing the context of the original question I wanted answered. I should probably go back to lurking, I don't seem to have much skill in expressing myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Think of a comic relief as a narrative device

Comic relief is a technique used by narrators (including GMs) to change the pace of the story, act as a foil, lampshade other techniques or even subvert entire genres. The idea is that your comic relief has to have both an **in-universe function** and **narrative function**. As a device it is handled pretty much the same regardless whether your comic relief is a character, a situation, a scene or even a location. The following will be presented as if you were introducing a character, but remember that instead of Manny the Fun Guy you can have The Fun Tavern, where antics happen or Funny Transformation Sequence that happens whenever your character casts a polymorph spell.

### In-universe function

Is a reason the character or situation is there in the first place. Without it your comic relief will be spotted immediately and called out for being an out of place, out of frame shoehorned klutz. Without it, you have a [Big Lipped Alligator](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BigLippedAlligatorMoment) (TVTropes, beware!).

### Narrative function

This is where you make up your mind about what you are trying to accomplish through your comic relief. If you want a change of pace, try to look for a **[breather](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/PlayingWith/BreatherLevel)**, a situation of safety and fun, where your characters can relax and your players regenerate. You may be looking for a [Foil](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Foil) whose main purpose is to highlight traits of another character. You can use them as your universe only source of light. Or it can be used to increase the tension several times over when your comic relief dies a gruesome death.

### Now not to go over the top?

Keep yourself to one function of each type. Make sure these functions are appropriate - if you have a wacky character lighting the mood of crime drama it's fine, but doing the same to already Chaotic Good adventures will be seen as clowning. Also, remember that comic reliefs are supposed to be appropriate for audience. Frozen might be quite a dark tale to young viewers and justify two comic relief characters, but their parents might just find the dancing snowman annoying.

### Example time!

A great comic reliefs in media would include Solaire of Astora from Dark Souls - he has a specific in-game function to help the character and provide information, while his narrative function is to show that happiness can be found in this dystopian world. Change of pace relief you can find in Anime, with [Obligatory Beach Episode](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BeachEpisode). A foil comic relief would be C3PO, socially inept upper class robot, underlining Luke's straightforward and knightly outlook. A BAD example would be Jar-Jar - a silly foil to pragmatic Obi-Wan, who himself is a foil to philosopher Qui-Gon. He went over the top, since there has already been funny moments between the Jedi ("Negotiations were short.") and his ludicrous behaviour was unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

For techniques of adding comic relief characters, think of your favorite animated movies. Often, the comic relief character is not one of the main protagonists, and thus does not critically influence the story. Importantly, the comic relief character doesn't just do comic relief. Sure, they frequently joke, or bumble, but they can be serious, sad, or angry. In other words, think of a comic relief character as a "mood indicating character".

The comic relief character, or sidekick, should have a predictable trigger, for example the talking vegan piggy that goes ballistic whenever there is bacon (the wizard who enchanted it wanted it to be a reminder he could no longer consume animal products due to a curse, but eventually decided he'd rather activate the curse for one last steak), or the talking hat would whistle at every "pretty" female passing by (enjoy explaining to the ogre lady that this was just your hat).

In addition, the sidekick should react emotionally, sometimes over the top, to how the world interacts with the party. If the party gets insulted, the pet monkey would start fling poo, if somebody gets badly injured, the pet monkey would rush towards them and try to kiss it better.

Finally, the sidekick should be inconsequential in combat and other encounters, but you may use them to give hints to the party, or to move conversations along if things start to drag.

In sum, use the comic relief character to bring emotions into the game, and sometimes do something funny.